# Cant change the background color of entire page with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to change the color of  body section  with the click of a button with `id="btn"`. but when I launch the `index.html` the background color is not changing. if any one has the solution please i want the concept behind the solution.

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="butn">
      <button type="button" id="btn">Click to change baackground</button>
    </div>
    <style src="main.js"></style>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.butn {
  margin-top: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 15rem;

  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

JS code:

```js
var color = [
  "AntiqueWhite",
  "CadetBlue",
  "BurlyWood",
  "Crimson",
  "DarkSlateBlue",
  "LightGoldenRodYellow",
  "LightCyan",
];
var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  changeBackground();
});

function changeBackground() {
  console.log(color[randomNumber]);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: with the first click, it is changing, on further clicks, it is not changing. Is this your problem?

Comment: NO it's not changing at all.

Comment: `style` tag for `main.js` should be replaced with `script` tag

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your js file should be in `script` tag and not in `style` tag.

Secondly, random number is getting generated only once when your js file loads, instead
move random number inside the changeBackground function, so that it can get a new number every time the button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

As the `randomNumber` variable is outside the function, it only gets initialized once.
So you have to move the `randomNumber` to the function to generate random color every time you click on the button.

**js**

```
function changeBackground() {
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
    console.log(color[randomNumber]);

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[randomNumber];
  }
```

And while including js file, you should write in this manner

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 6); inside the function changeBackground, otherwise it will only get this number once. This way, it gets a new number each time this function is called.

```
function changeBackground() {
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
  console.log(color[randomNumber]);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: @PailBaiju This was posted while I was answering!